# SQL works fine when run from Access query but fails when passed as SQL statement from VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I haven't been able to find an answer or solution to this and am hoping that someone here can help me with this.  The following SQL statement runs perfectly and returns the desired results when run from a query in Access (Create => Query Design => paste in SQL view).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ITMID 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON ((PRTID) = (Table1.ITMID)) AND ((Table2.PLT) = (Table1.PLT)) 
WHERE (((Table1.PLT) = '" & pltflag & "') AND ((Table1.MAKBUYIND) = 'M') AND ((Table2.ENDEFF) = 99999) AND ((Table2.CMPTYP) = 'E')) 
ORDER BY Table1.ITMID;
```

However, when I attempt to run the query from Excel VBA using the following code

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
    Set db = OpenDatabase(g400DBPath)
    sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ITMID FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON ((PRTID) = (Table1.ITMID)) AND ((Table2.PLT) = (Table1.PLT)) WHERE (((Table1.PLT) = '" & PltFlag & "') AND ((Table1.MAKBUYIND) = 'M') AND ((Table2.ENDEFF) = 99999) AND ((Table2.CMPTYP) = 'E')) ORDER BY Table1.ITMID;"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

It fails when attempting to execute the statement with the following error

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

> Run time error: 3296
>   Join Expression Not Supported

Comment: when you're building the sSQL string it looks like your missing line continuation characters.  I'd assume the compiler is complaining about that line?  Try inspecting the sSQL string before it's executed.

Comment: corrected the formatting here to match what is actually in my code window

Comment: "The following SQL statement runs perfectly" - how can that run when there is a `... = '" & pltflag & "') AND ...` in it?  Please copy into the question the exact SQL statement that does work.

Comment: @YowE3K, sorry about that, I forgot to change that bit back to the static data instead of the variable I am using in my code.  If I replace the concatenated variable with the constant '01' it runs fine.

Comment: I have however, managed to figure out what is causing it to fail but don't understand why it was causing it to fail, and if someone could shed some light on that I'd welcome it.

Fixing it was as simple as changing `INNER JOIN Table2 ON ((PRTID)` 
 
to
 
 `INNER JOIN Table2 ON ((Table1.PRTID)`
 
why the former would work when run from a query inside access and fail when passed through code I haven't a clue

Comment: But is that the actual statement?  I've never seen Access put parentheses around fields before (i.e. I would have expected `((Table2.PLT) = (Table1.PLT))` to be just `(Table2.PLT = Table1.PLT)` if you had copied the actual working SQL statement taken from Access) but if it **is** the working statement then my guess that `PRTID` should be `Table2.PRTID` won't be right.

Comment: It looks like you came up with the same guess as me while I was typing - but, again, I have never seen Access leave off the table name when creating the `ON` clause before, so I suggest you check what the actual working SQL was.

Comment: @YowE3K, yes that is the actual statement copied from the SQL view in access.  I'm using Access 2010

Comment: I'm currently using Access 2013, so **maybe** 2010 was lazier.

Comment: @YowE3K, wouldn't be the craziest thing I've seen in a MS product

Comment: Like @YowE3K - I cannot reproduce issue (though I also use Acc2013) and in all SQL measures, such syntax should be disallowed. Fields in `ON` clauses requires table references. Same ACE SQL engine in 2007-2016 versions. I wonder if OP mis-typed and thought a resultset outputted. Check very carefully. Does query really run and save effectively? Can you reproduce your original issue?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, I'm not at work, but maybe specify your table join `((Table2.PRTID) = (Table1.ITMID)) `